# Reporting Services in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am creating an rdlc report in VS 2010 .
When I see my report in reportviewer it seems OK to me but when i export that report to PDF its format changes and reportviewer format do not match with PDF format....
I want to have same format in report
How can i resolve this problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit difficult to answer without knowing exactly what changes but I would assume this is down to page widths etc as thats one of the most common issues I've seen.

Your PDF is going to render the data in pages to fit on whatever the default is, probably A4 for uk or I believe Letter for USA, so the best way to get consistent results is to set the page size of your report to whatever size you are going to be printing it out on, and have fixed sizes, do not let things resize on their own.

If you want to update your answer with what is changing I can possibly help you more.